# Gdal: how to get the max and min altitudes of my topographic raster?

Tags: raster, gdal, topography, srtm

Given a .tiff topographic raster image.

**How to get the altitudes of the highest and lowest point/pixel ?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With bash alone, you can use :

```
gdalinfo -mm input.tif
```

It returns a range of infos within which is the string `Computed Min/Max=-425.000,8771.000`, for my Eurasian raster.

Some cleanup and you get your vertical min/max variables:

```
$zMin=`gdalinfo -mm ./input.tif | sed -ne 's/.*Computed Min\/Max=//p'| tr -d ' ' | cut -d "," -f 1 | cut -d . -f 1`
$zMax=`gdalinfo -mm ./input.tif | sed -ne 's/.*Computed Min\/Max=//p'| tr -d ' ' | cut -d "," -f 2 | cut -d . -f 1`
$echo $zMin $zMax
>-425 8771
```

I trimed both the digits after decimal point and the spaces in case via `cut -d <separator> -f <selected_field>` and `tr -d ' '`, respectively. Adapt as needed.

Comment: Strangely, this does not have to be the same as the metadata. For an original SRTM hgt file:   `Min=-32.000 Max=202.000   Computed Min/Max=-58.000,205.000`. The computed values reflect the real content of the cells.

Answer (score 19):

With Python, you can access raster statistics using the [Python GDAL/OGR API](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/index.html).

```
from osgeo import gdal

# open raster and choose band to find min, max
raster = r'C:\path\to\your\geotiff.tif'
gtif = gdal.Open(raster)
srcband = gtif.GetRasterBand(1)

# Get raster statistics
stats = srcband.GetStatistics(True, True)

# Print the min, max, mean, stdev based on stats index
print "[ STATS ] =  Minimum=%.3f, Maximum=%.3f, Mean=%.3f, StdDev=%.3f" % (
    stats[0], stats[1], stats[2], stats[3])
```

---

```
>>> print "[ STATS ] =  Minimum=%.3f, Maximum=%.3f, Mean=%.3f, StdDev=%.3f" % (
...     stats[0], stats[1], stats[2], stats[3])
[ STATS ] =  Minimum=1.000, Maximum=4.000, Mean=1.886, StdDev=0.797
>>>
```

Comment: I used to sneer when reading answers using the Python GDAL/OGR API, thinking "Why would anyone suggest that when there's a perfectly good command-line way to do the same?" Now, that I have to programmatically do nearly everything, I'm super-grateful to answers like yours. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

**If the stats have already been calculated:**

```
gdalinfo input.tif
```

**If they haven't been calculated yet**, do:

```
gdal_translate -stats input.tif output.tif
gdalinfo output.tif
```

Comment: The altitude info is not there. Did you test it successfully ?

Comment: That should be the MINIMUM and MAXIMUM values returned by gdalinfo. You may have a problem if the NODATA value hasn't been set, in which case you may have a very low MINIMUM value (rarely a very high MAXIMUM instead).

Comment: `gdal_translate -stats SRTM_NE_250m.tif` & `gdalinfo -stats SRTM_NE_250m.tif` fails here. No min/max. Found with `gdalinfo -mm SRTM_NE_250m.tif` and appears as `Computed Min/Max=-425.000,8771.000` for my data.

Comment: The max value of 8771 looks correct with a 250m pixel size.

Comment: @Vesanto: I unvalidated your answer for the moment, since neither `gdal_translate` nor `gdalinfo -stats` work here. Jump in, edit your answer with  `gdalinfo -mm filename.tif` and so I could valide it again.

Comment: OK, gdal_translate -stats requires you create a new file, you can also set the nodata value at the same time. But given that gdalinfo -mm *.tif worked it would seem that the nodata value was already set. -mm is fine for a quick check but it solves one problem, once; calculating the stats properly will give you greater flexibility later.

Comment: Can you include the precises serie of commands you do ?  Nor `gdal_translate -stats` nor ` gdal_translate -stats SRTM_NE_250m.tif` don't work here, and don't create any file.

Comment: Well, I don't have room to show all the details but using a SPOT4 scene: ```gdalinfo SPOT4_HRVIR1_042-209_0_080831_111638.tif``` gave metadata but no min-max. the same command with -mm produced the min-max. ```gdal_translate -stats SPOT4_HRVIR1_042-209_0_080831_111638.tif output.tif``` produces a new file and ```gdalinfo output.tif ``` on that gives metadata with min-max values plus more

Comment: I've posted a more complete example on my blog (http://mercergeoinfo.blogspot.com/2014/03/gdalinfo-and-statistics.html). If that's against the rules here then I apologise now. Feel free to remove this if it is the case.

Comment: Would be good to do more solid answers with exact and full commands such `gdal_translate -stats input.tif output.tif`, `gdalinfo output.tif`, and shorter wording. That avoid unclear answer, series of comments to clarify, while link to your blog will be better accepted.

Comment: I've put colour highlighting on the commands. Most of the text is the output from ```gdalinfo``` and the 'short' version is a couple of comments above here. There isn't any more to it really, ```gdal_translate -stats fileIn.tif fileOut.tif``` then ```gdalinfo fileOut.tif```

Comment: This takes the long way around. Gdalinfo can calculate and record the stats in an .aux file without needing to create a new raster: `gdalinfo -stats someraster.tif` (this may not have been the case when this answer was first posted). Also see [How to get GDAL to create statistics for GTiff in Python](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29064/how-to-get-gdal-to-create-statistics-for-gtiff-in-python)

Comment: #pro-tip: if you're shrinking raster storage, e.g. by converting that huge 30+GB 32bit float to nice manageable 100MB 8bit, compute stats **after** using `gdalinfo -stats ...` and not during conversion. `gdal_translate -stats ...` computes statistics at the beginning before anything else, wasting a LOT of time.

Answer (score 3):

Using `gdalinfo` and `jq` you can get what you need in a succinct fashion. This assumes that band that has your min/max is the first one (change the index if not).

```
gdalinfo -json -mm  input.tif | jq .bands[0].computedMin

gdalinfo -json -mm  input.tif | jq .bands[0].computedMax
```

Comment: I needed to quote the jq selector
`gdalinfo -json -mm  input.tif | jq '.bands[0].computedMax'`

Answer (score -1):

For Maximum and Minimum Height I will Prefer this

```
from osgeo import gdal

raster = r'Path of your image'
gtif = gdal.Open(raster)
srcband = gtif.GetRasterBand(1)

stats = srcband.GetStatistics(True, True)

print ('[ STATS ] =  Minimum=%.3f, Maximum=%.3f, Mean=%.3f' % (
stats[0], stats[1], stats[2]))
```