# Looping through all raster cell values using GDAL via Python?

Tags: python, gdal, numpy

I'm trying to identify null/0 values in each of my raster bands. How can I loop through all the values of each band? I've tried this code, straight from the gdal/python cookbook website but this just gives stats for each band as a whole and for some reason it actually doesn't print a minimum value of 0 even though my raster does have 0 values, it shows a minimum value of 1.

I want to print every single cell value. Is there a way to do this?

```
from osgeo import gdal
import sys

src_ds = gdal.Open( "INPUT.tif" )

print "[ RASTER BAND COUNT ]: ", src_ds.RasterCount
for band in range( src_ds.RasterCount ):
    band += 1
    print "[ GETTING BAND ]: ", band
    srcband = src_ds.GetRasterBand(band)

    stats = srcband.GetStatistics( True, True )

    print "[ STATS ] =  Minimum=%.3f, Maximum=%.3f, Mean=%.3f, StdDev=%.3f" % ( \
            stats[0], stats[1], stats[2], stats[3] )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may read it as array, using numpy:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import sys
import numpy as np

src_ds = gdal.Open( "INPUT.tif" )

print "[ RASTER BAND COUNT ]: ", src_ds.RasterCount
for band in range( src_ds.RasterCount ):
    band += 1
    print "[ GETTING BAND ]: ", band
    srcband = src_ds.GetRasterBand(band)

    stats = srcband.GetStatistics( True, True )

    print "[ STATS ] =  Minimum=%.3f, Maximum=%.3f, Mean=%.3f, StdDev=%.3f" % ( \
            stats[0], stats[1], stats[2], stats[3] )

    rast_array = np.array(src_ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
    print rast_array
```

Using a sample raster, the above code will return:

```
[ RASTER BAND COUNT ]:  1
[ GETTING BAND ]:  1
[ STATS ] =  Minimum=1683.000, Maximum=1900.000, Mean=1820.854, StdDev=59.329
[[1900 1900 1898 1895 1892 1887 1879 1871 1863 1852 1845 1837 1824 1802
  1743 1725 1713 1705 1699 1693 1687 1683]
 [1897 1896 1894 1892 1890 1884 1877 1869 1862 1854 1847 1838 1820 1800
  1745 1729 1719 1712 1706 1701 1696 1695]
 [1892 1891 1890 1888 1885 1881 1875 1868 1861 1855 1849 1837 1817 1794
  1747 1732 1725 1720 1714 1710 1707 1706]
 [1887 1885 1884 1882 1880 1878 1873 1867 1860 1855 1849 1833 1815 1789
  1749 1738 1732 1728 1723 1720 1718 1715]
 [1882 1880 1878 1876 1875 1873 1871 1866 1861 1855 1849 1832 1817 1795
  1756 1744 1740 1737 1733 1730 1728 1725]
 [1880 1877 1874 1873 1870 1868 1867 1865 1860 1855 1850 1841 1834 1817
  1795 1769 1749 1746 1743 1740 1736 1731]
 [1880 1876 1873 1870 1869 1866 1863 1862 1859 1856 1852 1847 1843 1841
  1824 1812 1802 1775 1758 1747 1740 1733]
 [1879 1876 1873 1870 1869 1866 1863 1860 1858 1855 1852 1850 1847 1843
  1831 1819 1803 1782 1763 1747 1738 1730]
 [1879 1877 1874 1872 1869 1866 1864 1861 1858 1855 1852 1850 1850 1848
  1836 1816 1794 1775 1754 1744 1736 1728]
 [1880 1877 1875 1872 1869 1867 1864 1862 1858 1854 1850 1848 1850 1850
  1840 1806 1786 1767 1749 1742 1734 1726]
 [1881 1879 1876 1873 1870 1866 1864 1861 1857 1851 1843 1840 1841 1850
  1827 1797 1782 1769 1752 1742 1733 1723]
 [1882 1879 1876 1873 1870 1867 1864 1861 1855 1848 1839 1835 1833 1836
  1810 1794 1783 1771 1758 1747 1737 1729]
 [1882 1880 1876 1873 1869 1866 1862 1858 1854 1849 1838 1833 1826 1814
  1800 1792 1782 1773 1762 1752 1742 1733]
 [1881 1878 1874 1870 1867 1863 1860 1856 1853 1849 1840 1835 1821 1813
  1798 1790 1783 1774 1766 1757 1748 1738]]
```

(If you want to print each value separately, it could be easy to edit the code).

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted. I've never worked with numpy. So it's making a bunch of arrays made up of individual cell values? So the first number 1900, that is the value of a singe cell correct? How does it determine number of values in each array?

Comment: Yes. The first array store the cell values starting from the up-left of the raster, and so on.

Answer (score 4):

The problem has been resolved  in  [GDAL does not ignore NoData value](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/29076/2581)

```
 f = gdal.Open("a.tif")
 bands = f.RasterCount
 print bands 
 3
 for j in range(bands):
       band = f.GetRasterBand(j+1)
       stats = band.GetStatistics( True, True )
       print "[ STATS ] =  Minimum=%.3f, Maximum=%.3f, Mean=%.3f, StdDev=%.3f" % ( stats[0], stats[1], stats[2], stats[3] )
 [ STATS ] =  Minimum=17.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=220.586, StdDev=39.705
 [ STATS ] =  Minimum=64.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=214.975, StdDev=36.926
 [ STATS ] =  Minimum=45.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=179.029, StdDev=68.234
```

But if you use `band.ReadAsArray()` (= Numpy array)

```
for j in range(bands):
    band = f.GetRasterBand(j+1)
    data = band.ReadAsArray()
    print "[ Numpy ] =  Minimum=%.3f, Maximum=%.3f, Mean=%.3f, StdDev=%.3f" % (data.min(), data.max(), data.mean(), data.std())
[ Numpy ] =  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=220.477, StdDev=42.584
[ Numpy ] =  Minimum=31.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=214.955, StdDev=39.558
[ Numpy ] =  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=178.856, StdDev=69.535
```

Why? The problem is ([GDAL does not ignore NoData value](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/29076/2581))

> GetStatistics will reuse previously computed statistics if they exist (i.e computed before you set the NoData value). You can use **stats = band.ComputeStatistics(0) instead of GetStatistics to force the statistics to be recomputed.**

```
for j in range(bands):
    band = f.GetRasterBand(j+1)
    stats = band.ComputeStatistics(0)
    print "[ STATS ] =  Minimum=%.3f, Maximum=%.3f, Mean=%.3f, StdDev=%.3f" % ( stats[0], stats[1], stats[2], stats[3] ) 

[ STATS ] =  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=220.477, StdDev=42.584
[ STATS ] =  Minimum=31.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=214.955, StdDev=39.558
[ STATS ] =  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=178.856, StdDev=69.535
```

Answer (score 2):

...Or you could just convert it to an ESRI Ascii Raster and achieve effectively the same result in much less time.

Here's an example of an ascii raster from the [documentation](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/java/GP_ToolRef/spatial_analyst_tools/esri_ascii_raster_format.htm):

```
ncols 480
nrows 450
xllcorner 378923
yllcorner 4072345
cellsize 30
nodata_value -32768

43 2 45 7 3 56 2 5 23 65 34 6 32 54 57 34 2 2 54 6 
35 45 65 34 2 6 78 4 2 6 89 3 2 7 45 23 5 8 4 1 62 ...
```

GDAL can do the conversion very fast, you can then read the file, or whatever is required.  There is nothing wrong with the other answer.   I only suggest this because I find NUMPY very slow for cell-by-cell operations.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: This is another option, but I preferred to adapt the answer starting from its code =)

Comment: Yeah - your answer is perfectly fine/correct.  I'm just used to processing way too much data and look for alternative routes that save time (though are often admittedly a little left-field)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to create a new raster that contains the sum of all pixelvalues of the raster contained in a folder.
Is it possible?

```
os.chdir(r'C:/TifFolder')
li_rasters = [raster for raster in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if os.path.splitext(raster)[-1] == '.tiff']
#print (li_rasters)

#final_band=(r'C:/Users/KIFF/Desktop/These/data/Results/result.tiff')

for raster in li_rasters:
......
```